# Python shutil copy to network folder OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Tags: python, shutil

I am using shutil.copy to copy a file in the remote network server

```
shutil.copy(r'ebw.json', r'\\xx.xx.xx.xx\ebw.json')
```

The following error i am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ebw.py", line 93, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(r'bwe.json'), os.path.join(r'\\xx.xx.xx.xx\ebw.json'))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\ebw.json'
```

Comment: Is `\\xx.xx.xx.xx\ ` mounted on your local filesystem?

Comment: Network folder from local to \\192.168.1.2

Comment: So from a command prompt, you can type `copy myfile.txt \\xx.xx.xx.xx\myfile.txt` and it will work?

Comment: yes it works with cmd and powershell but i am trying with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-sharing the folder the issue got fixed.
Thank you